# Html unordered list, problems with bullet points

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following html for a unordered list, but bullet points are displayed far from the list items.

[Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dq7P.png)

```css
.right-block ul li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(../img/list_marker.png) 0 5px no-repeat;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="right-block-title"><h3>Categories</h3></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You want something like that below:**

Then just add `padding:0` of `<ul>`

[image]

```css
.right-block ul li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7Ta/pbq/7TapbqgGc.png) 0 5px no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: left center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 29px;
}

.right-block ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="right-block-title">
      <h3>Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin` & `Padding` `0` on `ul`

```
.right-block ul
  {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `ul` tag take 60px padding from left

```css
.right-block ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.right-block ul li {
 list-style: none;
 background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=10%C3%9710&w=10&h=10&txtpad=1) 0 5px no-repeat;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
 <div class="right-block">
  <div class="right-block-title"><h3>Categories</h3></div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and *only* replaced the background image with another image, and it works.

So either you have a `padding-left` in a CSS rule which you didn't post here, or your image contains a big (transparent and therefore invisible) space on its right side.

```css
.right-block ul li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/14x14/00f) 0 5px no-repeat;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="right-block">

    <div class="right-block-title">
      <h3>Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margins or paddings on your complete list. if this doesn't work you can try to give your image a max-width. wich if it is under 100% will shorteb the width at the right side. Don't think this will solve it tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```css
.right-block ul {

   padding: 0;
   
}
.right-block ul li {

   list-style: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;    
}

.right-block ul li:before {

  content: " ";
  background-image:url(http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~powerjg/files/bullet_triangle_grey.png);
  background-size: 30px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px; 
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="right-block">
    
      <div class="right-block-title"><h3>Categories</h3></div>
          <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```